# RegEX to replace <div /foo> with </div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, regex-negation

I'm a newbie in using RegEX and I could really use some help.

I'm doing some string replacements and I currently get the output

```
<div /foo>
```

Instead of

```
</div>
```

---

```
str = "[foo][/foo]";
```

Regex used:

```
str= str.replace(/\[/g, '<div ').replace(/\]/g, '>');
```

Output wanted:

```
<div foo></div>
```

---

Can someone help me to replace the string in the right way?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Impossible to help without some context

Comment: What is the expected output of `[foo][/foo]`?

Comment: Added required output as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one could suit your needs:

```
\[([^\]]+)\](.*?)\[/\1\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Replace with: `<div $1>$2</div>`

- Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0e-bctlnTXalpvjb)
- Demo on [RegExr](http://regexr.com?38dgt)

PS: don't forget to escape the `/` if using JavaScript's regex literal, i.e.:

`/\[([^\]]+)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]/g`

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, thank you for the demos and visualization!

Answer (score 3):

Not much content to your question so I just posted something which gets the job done. Note this assumes you do not care about anything after the opening tag, it only keeps the name of the tag and replaces it by `</tagname>`.

```
var str = "<div /foo>";
var replaced = str.replace(/<(\w+).*/, '</$1>')
// "</div>"
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @M42 How so? Did I miss something? It replaces "<div /foo>" with "</div>" does it not?

Comment: yes but OP wants to replace `[foo][/foo]` by `<div foo></div>`

Comment: if the desired output is `<div foo></div>` then try this

`var str = "<div /foo>";
var replaced = str.replace(/<(\w+) \/(\w+)>?/, function (match, $1, $2) {console.log('d', arguments); return '<'+$1+' '+$2+'></'+$1+'>';});`

Comment: @M42 He changed his question. That content wasn't there when I answered, only the title was any indication. All content below `</div>` was added, starting at `str = "[foo][/foo]";`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
str= str.replace(/\[(.+?)\]\[\/\1\]/g, '<div $1></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also.

```
var  str = "[foo][/foo]";
//replace <, > with [, ]
var signReplace = str.replace(/\[/g, '<').replace(/\]/g, '>'); 
tagReplace = signReplace.replace(/foo/g, 'div'); //replace div with foo
```